# String array not deallocated upon scope exit

Tags: c, arduino

I am running into some serious memory leaks in my application, so I setup this extremely bare solution to test what happens when a String array goes out of scope...

I know that the old TextString implementation of String was lacking a destructor, but this current implementation seems to have it.

I am using [this MemoryFree library](http://arduino.cc/playground/Code/AvailableMemory) (**Note this linked code has now been fixed based on the accepted answer to this question**).

The code examines two scenarios: Allocation of char array and string array in two different functions to force scope exit on both.

```
#include <MemoryFree.h>

void setup() {
  // put your setup code here, to run once:
  Serial.begin(9600);
  int freeBefore, freeAfter;

  //TEST ALLOCATION OF CHAR ARRAY//
  freeBefore = freeMemory();
  AllocateCharArr();
  freeAfter = freeMemory();
  Serial.println("CHAR*: Before " + String(freeBefore)
    + ", After " + String(freeAfter)
    + ", Diff " + String(freeBefore - freeAfter));

  //TEST ALLOCATION OF STRING//
  freeBefore = freeMemory();
  AllocateStringArr();
  freeAfter = freeMemory();
  Serial.println("STRING: Before " + String(freeBefore)
    + ", After " + String(freeAfter)
    + ", Diff " + String(freeBefore - freeAfter));
}

void AllocateCharArr() {
  char s[100];
}

void AllocateStringArr() {
  String s[100];
}

void loop() { /* empty */ }
```

Output:

> CHAR*: Before 1710, After 1710, Diff 0 
>   STRING: Before 1645, After 1309, Diff 336

How come the `String` array allocation is not wiped from memory?

Comment: What is the result when the `String` array is much smaller (e.g., 10 elements)?

Comment: Interesting: 
50 elements=diff 136,
25 elements=diff 36,
10 elements=diff 0

Comment: What version of the Arduino software are you using (0023, 1.0, ...)?

Comment: I'm using software version 1.0, running it on a Arduino UNO R3 board with ATmega328 controller.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have come across memory handling issues in Arduino versions prior to 1.0 when testing the `String` class ([see forum post here](http://arduino.cc/pipermail/developers_arduino.cc/2011-June/005151.html)).

The String constructor uses `realloc` internally and it's this (avr libc) dynamic memory handling that was causing the problems (due to the pointer to the top of the heap `__brkval` not being updated upon `free()`).

Run the following code to see these issues in versions 0023, 0022, etc. In Arduino 1.0 the code should show no memory leaks:

```
#if (ARDUINO >= 100)
#include <Arduino.h>
#else
#include <WProgram.h>
#endif
#include <HardwareSerial.h>
#include <MemoryFree.h>

void setup() {
  // put your setup code here, to run once:
  Serial.begin(9600);
  int freeBefore, freeAfter;

  freeBefore = freeMemory();

  void* buffer = malloc(10);
  if (buffer == 0) {
    Serial.println("Failed to allocate memory");
  }
  free(buffer);

  freeAfter = freeMemory();
  Serial.println("Before " + String(freeBefore)
    + ", After " + String(freeAfter)
    + ", Diff " + String(freeBefore - freeAfter));
}

void loop() {
}
```

In addition, the MemoryFree library you are using can give wrong results as it doesn't take into account the free list. Try this updated version of `MemoryFree.cpp`:

```
extern unsigned int __heap_start;
extern void *__brkval;

/*
 * The free list structure as maintained by the 
 * avr-libc memory allocation routines.
 */
struct __freelist {
  size_t sz;
  struct __freelist *nx;
};

/* The head of the free list structure */
extern struct __freelist *__flp;

#include "MemoryFree.h";

/* Calculates the size of the free list */
int freeListSize() {
  struct __freelist* current;
  int total = 0;

  for (current = __flp; current; current = current->nx) {
    total += 2; /* Add two bytes for the memory block's header  */
    total += (int) current->sz;
  }

  return total;
}

int freeMemory() {
  int free_memory;

  if ((int)__brkval == 0) {
    free_memory = ((int)&free_memory) - ((int)&__heap_start);
  } else {
    free_memory = ((int)&free_memory) - ((int)__brkval);
    free_memory += freeListSize();
  }
  return free_memory;
}
```

Comment: Thank you! It turned out it was the freeMemory function that reported bad values. Using your supplied method instead, gives correct results and no leak seems to occur.

Comment: Good to know the Arduino 1.0 libraries are OK. Will update the answer. Thanks!

Comment: I've updated the MemoryFree.cpp library code on the Arduino site (http://arduino.cc/playground/Code/AvailableMemory) in line with this accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you look through the [Arduino source](http://code.google.com/p/arduino/downloads/detail?name=arduino-1.0-src.tar.gz&can=2&q=), you might come across the file ".\arduino-1.0\hardware\arduino\cores\arduino\WString.cpp". In this file, I noticed that String does not have a default (parameterless) constructor. Perhaps this could be the problem? Doubtful, but anyway, the source should help. Best of luck.

Comment: I've been looking into that file already, primarily to verify that it had a destructor. I will test to see if an array initialized with values makes any difference.

Answer (score 0):

Comment out the line `String s[100];` and see if you get different results. It looks like the memory allocations you're seeing are due to the string operations in your `setup()` function, not to the declaration of a local array of strings in `AllocateStrArr()`. You can take a look at [WString.cpp](https://github.com/arduino/Arduino/blob/master/hardware/arduino/cores/arduino/WString.cpp) and [WString.h](https://github.com/arduino/Arduino/blob/master/hardware/arduino/cores/arduino/WString.h) to see that `operator+` has been overridden, so every call to `String()` or concatenation using `+` could create another object.

Comment: Commenting that line brings its to diff 0.